# How to remove print and share action from a form odoo 12

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-12, odoo-view

Hi I'm using odoo 12 I'd like to remove an action button from a form

[image: print action]

and also the share inside the action menu:

[image: remove share menu]

I did the following in the inherited view without results:

```
 <record model="ir.ui.view" id="sale_order_log_notes">
    <field name="name">sale.order.log.notes</field>
    <field name="model">sale.order</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">

    <xpath expr="//form" position="attributes">    
        <attribute name="share">0</attribute>
        <attribute name="print">0</attribute>
    </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Quotation / Order` action was added using the [report](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/addons/sale/report/sale_report.xml#L4) shortcut to `ir.action.report` and the [Share](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/addons/sale/data/sale_data.xml#L10) button was added using a server action.

There are already two buttons in the corresponding form views to unlink the actions (as mentioned by `mingtwo_h9`), a button named `Remove from the 'print' menu` to remove the action from the print dropdown menu and `Remove Contextual Action` button to remove an action from the dropdown action menu, both buttons call the `unlink_action` method, which is implemented separately for [ir.actions.report](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_actions_report.py#L165) and [ir.actions.server](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_actions.py#L436) and when called sets the `binding_model_id` field to `False` which hides the action.

It is possible to make a call to a method on a model using the [function](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/reference/data.html#function) tag.

> It has two mandatory parameters `model` and `name` specifying respectively the model and the name of the method to call.

> Parameters can be provided using `eval` (should evaluate to a sequence of parameters to call the method with) or `value` elements (see `list` values).

We need to call the `unlink_action` method and pass the action record as a parameter

```
<function model="ir.actions.report" name="unlink_action"
          eval="[ref('sale.action_report_saleorder')]"/>

<function model="ir.actions.server" name="unlink_action" 
          eval="[ref('sale.model_sale_order_action_share')]"/>
```

You can also pass parameters using the `value` tag (there is an example in [l10n_generic_coa](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/addons/l10n_generic_coa/data/account_invoice_demo.xml#L28))

```
<function model="ir.actions.report" name="unlink_action">
    <value eval="[ref('sale.action_report_saleorder')]"/>
</function>

<function model="ir.actions.server" name="unlink_action">
    <value eval="[ref('sale.model_sale_order_action_share')]"/>
</function>
```

Answer (score 1):

The report and action need to be touched directly, not through the view.

For the report, go to `Settings` - `Technical` - `Actions` - `Reports`, open the report you need to remove and click the `Remove from the "Print' menu` button in the upper right button box of the form.

For the action, it is under `Settings` - `Technical` - `Actions` - `Server Actions`, to remove an action, click the `REMOVE CONTEXTAL ACTION` button in the header of the form. Note that standard actions like `Delete` and `Duplicate` cannot be removed this way.